# Set a default constructor for an element in an unordered_map in case of [] operator

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have this class:

```
class test_t {

public:

  int value;

  test_t() { }

  test_t(int _value) : value(_value) { }

};
```

Now I have create a unordered_map with the a int value as key

```
std::unordered_map<int, test_t> map;
```

When I will use the operator [] if the key it not exist a new element will be add to the map calling the construct.

```
test_t & test = map[0];
```

Now it si possible to tell to the unordered_map to call the other constructor?
i.e. is is possibile to do something like this?

```
std::unordered_map<int, test_t(5)> map;
```

in the means that every new element will be create whit the construction with value 5?

I know that i can create a construction like this:

```
test_t(int _value = 5) { }
```

however the class test is only a example of something more complex.

Comment: `operator []` will call the default constructor of class `test_t` object. Before `test_t &test = map[0]`, you can add a check if that key exists in the map. If not, then you can insert an element with value of your choice passed to the constructor of class `test_t` object.

Comment: `test_t() { }` -- You should initialize the `_value` member even in this case.

Comment: One thing you can do is make your default ctor *configurable* so that it performs a specific initialization when it is next called. In your example it could be a public static member `static int initValue;` or such, and the ctor would be `test_t(): _value(initValue) { }`. For more complex classes you may want to define a struct which holds the important values for initialization and make that a static member. You can also get fancy and pass functors, much like [iomanipulators.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[] operator` value initialize the mapped value if it didn't find it and you cannot change it. You can change your default initializer though.

```
test_t() { value = 5;}
```

If you want to insert the value of your choice in case if the key is not in the map, one way would be using [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) to get an iterator to the key value pair and if the iterator was `end` iterator, then insert your key value pair.

Optionally as @PaulMcKenzie suggested, you can just use [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert), as "it returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place."

```
m.insert({key, test_t(5)});
```

Comment: *If you want to insert the value of your choice, the easiest way would be using find to get an iterator to the key value pair and if the iterator was end iterator, then insert your key value pair.* -- In this case, you can do this all in one call to `map::insert`, no need to call `find`. For example `map.insert({0, test_t(5)});`